# Permission denied inside docker container for buildozer

Tags: docker, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I am using docker container for packaging kivy for android. Getting below error. Any pointers is appreciated.
My local system is MacOS.
python 2.7.15

```
saurabhs-MacBook-Pro:~ saurabhshrivastava$ sudo docker run --privileged -v /Users/saurabhshrivastava/saurabh/kivy/practice/test:/buildozer/  -v /etc/udev/rules.d/:/etc/udev/rules.d/ tshirtman/buildozer buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.10 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git clone -b stable --single-branch https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git python-for-android-master'
# Cwd /buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'python-for-android-master': Permission denied
# Command failed: git clone -b stable --single-branch https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git python-for-android-master
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Did you add `/etc/` to shared folders in Docker's preferences? Asking because you try to map it into your host system via `-v`

Comment: How to do that. I am using a public image.

Comment: Click on your docker icon on the top bar, select `preferences` and go to `file sharing`

Comment: getting this error:- "The path /etc/ is reserved by Docker however it may be possible to export specific subdirectories."

Comment: Then you should try sharing a more specific location like `/etc/udev/` or `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. Now we see that your container is not actually accessing the `rules` from your host machine